# What if I open Windows Application.exe which contains Viruses in Wine, it will harm my Linux os too?

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine, malware

If I use a Windows program in Wine that is affected by a virus, can it harm my Linux operating system and other files too?
How I can avoid Windows viruses in Linux? Or there is another way to run to open .exe file.